# Use Wrapper classes as key and value when instantiating a Map

Tags: java, generics, primitive

I have a question concerning some semantics when instantiating a Map. Specifically, should I use the Wrapper class when assigning the key and value type, or is it okay to use primitive types?

**Example:**

```
Map<int, String> map = new TreeMap<int, String>();
```

OR

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
```

**Example:**

```
Map<int[], String> map = new TreeMap<int[], String>();
```

OR

```
Map<Integer[], String> map = new TreeMap<Integer[], String>();
```

Is there any difference between the two instantiations, in terms of both convention and meaning? I know using primitive types invokes Autoboxing when the object is read or written to.

Comment: Did you try any of these options to see which ones actually compile?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The least you could do is check if any of the code snippets posted does compile.

Comment: Realized only Wrapper classes are allowed after compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a primitive type in a generic type specification (such as `Map<int, String>` you suggested above), so you'll have to use the wrapper classes (i.e., `Map<Integer, String>` for this usecase). You can, of course, still use primitives when **calling** such a class' methods, as the primitive would be autoboxed (e.g., `myMap.put(7, 'Some String')`.

Arrays are a different question. Primitive arrays are in fact Objects so you could use them in generic specifications. However, arrays don't override the `equals(Object)` and `hashCode()` methods (regardless of whether they're arrays of primitives or objects), which makes them a very poor choice for map keys.

Comment: Thumbs up for the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

`Primitives` can not be used in generics. So you *have* to use `Wrapper Types`.

But using primitive arrays is okay, because Java-Arrays are always `objects`.

If you want to use primitives then have a look at [Project Valhalla](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/). Which wants to get rid of a lot of garbage in java and implements `Value Types` (similar to `primitives`)

Comment: By Primary Types you mean primitives ?

Comment: @c0der oh yeah thanks, fixed that

Answer (score 1):

Map does not allow `primitive` type as `key` or `value`. `int[]` works because according to [Java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) `array` is an `Object`.

If you want to use custom object as `key/value` you should either make that class immutable or have to override `hashCode()` and `equals()` method.